# mongodb replica set members unable to join in cluster over SSL

Tags: mongodb, ssl, mongodb-query

I have configured MongoDB replica set with 3 nodes below is MongoDB.conf file, replica set members are not able to join in the cluster.

```
  systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

storage:
  dbPath: /data/iddi
  journal:
    enabled: true

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  ssl:
      mode: requireSSL
      PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
      CAFile: /etc/ssl/CA.pem
      clusterFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem

security:
 keyFile: /opt/mongo-keyfile
# authorization: enabled
 clusterAuthMode: x509


replication:
  replSetName: mongod
```

below are the logs of primary server and secondary

```
    2018-07-03T12:08:56.107+0000 I REPL_HB  [replexec-3] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 8090) to node1.mongod:27018, response status: Unauthorized: command replSetHeartbeat requires authentication
2018-07-03T12:08:56.606+0000 I REPL_HB  [replexec-3] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 8091) to node2.mongod:27019, response status: Unauthorized: command replSetHeartbeat requires authentication
2018-07-03T12:08:56.607+0000 I REPL_HB  [replexec-3] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 8092) to node1.mongod:27018, response status: Unauthorized: command replSetHeartbeat requires authentication
2018-07-03T12:08:57.106+0000 I REPL_HB  [replexec-3] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 8093) to node2.mongod:27019, response status: Unauthorized: command replSetHeartbeat requires authentication
2018-07-03T12:08:57.107+0000 I REPL_HB  [replexec-3] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 8094) to node1.mongod:27018, response status: Unauthorized: command replSetHeartbeat requires authentication
```

secondary server logs

```
2018-07-03T10:48:45.695+0000 I ACCESS   [conn8] Failed to authenticate CN=mongod@$external from client 172.17.0.1:46320 with mechanism MONGODB-X509: UserNotFound: Could not find user CN=mongod@$external
2018-07-03T10:48:45.696+0000 I NETWORK  [conn8] end connection 172.17.0.1:46320 (0 connections now open)
2018-07-03T10:48:45.697+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.17.0.1:46328 #9 (1 connection now open)
2018-07-03T10:48:45.702+0000 I NETWORK  [conn9] received client metadata from 172.17.0.1:46328 conn9: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceTL", version: "4.0.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) ", architecture: "x86_64", version: "Kernel 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64" } }
2018-07-03T10:48:45.703+0000 I ACCESS   [conn9]  authenticate db: $external { authenticate: 1, mechanism: "MONGODB-X509", user: "CN=mongod", $db: "$external" }
2018-07-03T10:48:45.703+0000 I ACCESS   [conn9] Failed to authenticate CN=mongod@$external from client 172.17.0.1:46328 with mechanism MONGODB-X509: UserNotFound: Could not find user CN=mongod@$external
2018-07-03T10:53:35.211+0000 I CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval: Replication has not yet been configured
```

Comment: What's your replicaset config rs.conf()? What are the member certificates subjects (and did you conform to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-member-authentication/#certificate-requirements)?

Comment: rs.conf is node1.mongod,node2.mongod,node3.mongod........ and .... i placed same certificate on all nodes which subject name is *.mongod

Comment: I mean the output of this `openssl x509 -noout -subject -in /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem`

Comment: subject= /CN=mongod

Comment: Then you need more attributes in your subject, at least one of: Organization (O), the Organizational Unit (OU) or the Domain Component (DC). See an example how to generate those: https://gist.github.com/kevinadi/96090f6f9973ff8c2d019bbe0d9a0f70

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your member certificates used for internal authentication of the cluster members (in this case `/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem`) should have more properties in the keys `subject`. From the [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-member-authentication/#certificate-requirements):

> The Distinguished Name (DN), found in the member certificate’s subject, must specify a non-empty value for at least one of the following attributes: Organization (O), the Organizational Unit (OU) or the Domain Component (DC).

A good tutorial (with some proper explanation) of how to generate these certificates can be found [here](http://www.allanbank.com/blog/security/tls/x.509/2014/10/13/tls-x509-and-mongodb/).

Comment: I am facing similar issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438972/mongodb-cluster-internal-authentication-fails-on-for-replicaset-join-replsethe
I checked subject line from certificates, it does have CN and DC part