# MongoDB Cluster internal authentication fails on for replicaset join - replSetHeartbeat requires authentication

Tags: mongodb

Getting below error when I am adding second node the existing replicaset :

```
    {
    "ok"=>0.0, 
    "errmsg"=>"Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: devshard1s1:27018; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: devshard1s2:27018 failed with command replSetHeartbeat requires authentication", 
    "code"=>74, 
    "codeName"=>"NodeNotFound"
    }
```

failed with command replSetHeartbeat requires authentication

I have SSL enabled , authorization enabled and cluster authentication is also enabled :
snippet from /etc/mongodb.conf

```
  net:
    port: 27018
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0
    ssl:
      mode: requireSSL
      PEMKeyFile: "/etc/mongodb/ssl/cluster-cert.pem"
      CAFile: "/etc/mongodb/ssl/ca-cert.pem"
      clusterFile: "/etc/mongodb/ssl/cluster-cert.pem"
  security:
    clusterAuthMode: x509
    authorization: enabled
```

My CN name and SAN from devshard1s1 (first node) is :
`Subject: CN=10.0.41.239, DC=dev
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:devshard1s1, IP Address:10.0.41.239, IP Address:127.0.0.1, DNS:localhost`

My CN name and SAN from devshard1s2 (second node) is :
`Subject: CN=10.0.12.231, DC=dev
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:devshard1s2, IP Address:10.0.12.231, IP Address:127.0.0.1, DNS:localhost`

Also in PRIMARY node (devshard1s1) logs have this :

```
2019-01-29T13:57:57.639+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2131] can't authenticate to devshard1s2:27018 as internal user, error: Could not find user CN=10.0.41.239/DC=dev@$external
```

MongoDB Version :
4.0

Note :
I am following below approch to install (using chef)
1. Install 1st node from replicaset, since it is first, initialize replicaset so that it will become primary node.
2. Add admin user on this node with root role.
3. Install 2nd node from replicaset, since replicast already initialized, connect to PRIMARY, authenticate and reconfig replicaset with this node details.
4. While reconfiguring replicset got above error :  `Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: devshard1s1:27018; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: devshard1s2:27018 failed with command replSetHeartbeat requires authentication`

Comment: Check host info is correctly assigned in the X.509 certificate, /etc/mongodb/ssl/cluster-cert.pem.

Comment: What do you mean by host info ? do you mean CN ? It is correctly added in subject as shown above

Comment: Does that match the output of `hostname -s` on the member?

Comment: As per mongodb doc (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-member-authentication/),  `Either the Common Name (CN) or one of the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) entries must match the hostname of the server, used by the other members of the cluster.`, My certificate CN has IP address of host and SAN contains DNS entry of hostnames, still it gives auth error. I am able to use keyfile for internal auth, seems my certs are having issues, but what is that issue ?

Comment: If you're willing to try...  Is your OU "Dev"?  I saw it tried to authenticated the Dev user against `$external` database.  I ran into similar problem where the server considered the cluster auth request was from a client, and rejected it.  Remove the `PEMKeyFile` from your config and try again.  If it works, make sure your client certs do have the same OU as your server's pem.

Comment: I tried with KeyFile based internal authentication,. and it works,  so seems issue with certs generated,  I am using same certificate in `PEMKeyFile` and `ClusterFile` option, alos while connecting to mongo using my ruby client, I am using same cert from `PEMKeyFile`, where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Was it a self-signed cert?  You need a different client cert with a different OU from your servers'.